# WPF event capture. control firing mouseup but not mousedown

Tags: wpf, events, mouse, mouseup

I've read a few articles on related issues and this one seems to be inconsistent.

I have a datagrid control in which I need to capture mouse location when the mouse is clicked. I have code to do this in the mouseup and mousedown event handlers. mousedown is what I want, but that event is never fired. I put the code there and set a breakpoint and it never reaches that point. the mouseup however does fire just as it should, but its not the event I need and I'm getting unpredictable results.

are there any articles on this to explain what's happening? I assume its some kind of a routed event issue. but why would mouseup work but mousedown not? How can I fix my code so that all the events fire when they should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is happening because the cells in the datagrid are capturing the MouseDown events. You can try to subscribe to that event in code via:

```
DataGridName.AddHandler(MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(DataGridName_MouseDown), true);
```

Or if that's not what you're wanting to do there's also, I believe, a PreviewMouseDown event that's already assigned to a DataGrid that you can use.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Simple enough, and that seemed to work. that's really strange that such workarounds are necessary in WPF. in forms I'm just used to events firing. if you have a mousedown event and you mousedown the control, the event just fires like you'd expect. is there anything you know if I could read to explain the rhyme and reason behind this rather bizarre wpf behavior? -Thanks again for the solution!